# Bootstrap not working in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have set up a new rails app, which I want to use with Bootstrap. I have added:

```
/* *** gemfile *** */
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'autoprefixer-rails'
```

My `application.scss` file:

```
/*
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 */
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
```

my application.js file:

```
//= require jquery
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

everything else is default, I have run bundle install, but still my `http://localhost:3000/widgets` file is just the default html, not the bootstrap defaults.

Why is this and how do I debug it?

Comment: Just to make it clear, because your wording could mean either the css is not applied or you assume it would change the html: you have to change the html of `widgets` yourself and use the bootstrap classes to see a change in layout. Also, if you have used the scaffolding, you have to remove the scaffolded css file.

Comment: @nathanvda I do have the scaffolding css, but I don't see why having that would stop application.scss from working? I have included the default bootstrap nav class in html, so am waiting for that to render as a sign bootstrap is working?

Comment: Well, scaffolding css messes up the default bootstrap font definition. But as I said: it was unclear tome what you ment. The scaffolding css will not overrule nav class ;)

Answer (score 1):

You missed this part of [the documentation](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass):

Then, remove all the `*= require_self` and `*= require_tree .` statements from the sass file. Instead, use `@import` to import Sass files.

Comment: that is all in my `application.css.sass` file? Like this ` /*
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 *= require bootstrap
 */
//= require bootstrap` unfortunately that doesn't work.

Comment: can you post your entire application.css file

Comment: The code posted in my question is the whole file `app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss`

Comment: see update - you need to remove the require statements and use @import for each css file that you want to include

Comment: do you have //= require jquery
//= require bootstrap-sprockets in your application.js file?

Comment: Yes, I have added it to the question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104897/discussion-between-andrew-hendrie-and-george-edwards).

Answer (score 0):

Got it...  was missing this:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all' %>
```

from my `application.html.erb` file!